# Python: Shuffle and put back into initial order elements of an numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have an array on which I must modify some values. In order to do so, I have to change the order of elements of the array, after having changed its values, I want to put the values back into their initial order. But I have not managed to find out how.

When changing the order, I need to sort them from the biggest to the smallest element in absolute value. Then, I need to have the sum of elements being = to 1 so I modify the elements but then it's impossible to reorder the array.

This is my code:

```
output = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (4, 1)).ravel()

sorted_weigths = np.sort(abs(output))[::-1]
sorted_indices = np.argsort(sorted_weigths)[::-1] 
signs = [i < 0 for i in output]  

if np.sum(abs(sorted_weigths)) > 1:
    alloc = 1
    for i in range(output.shape[0]):
        if alloc > abs(sorted_weigths[i]):
            sorted_weigths[i] = sorted_weigths[i]
            alloc = alloc - abs(sorted_weigths[i])
        elif alloc > 0:
            sorted_weigths[i] = alloc
            alloc = alloc - alloc
        else:
            sorted_weigths[i] = 0
else:
    pass

sorted_weigths[sorted_indices]

for i in range(len(signs)):
    if signs[i] == True:
        sorted_weigths[i] = -sorted_weigths[i]
    else:
        pass
```

I know that

```
output = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (4, 1)).ravel()
sorted_weigths = np.sort(abs(output))
sorted_indices = np.argsort(sorted_weigths)
output[np.argsort(np.sort(abs(output)))]
```

This is the trick but modifying the values of output doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually to reorder the positions of the transformed array according to the ones of the original output, and not by keeping track of the shuffled indices.

The solution is:

```
output = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (4, 1)).ravel()

sorted_weigths = np.sort(abs(output))[::-1]
sorted_indices = np.argsort(abs(output))[::-1] 
signs = [i < 0 for i in output]  

if np.sum(abs(sorted_weigths)) > 1:
    alloc = 1
    for i in range(output.shape[0]):
        if alloc > abs(sorted_weigths[i]):
            sorted_weigths[i] = sorted_weigths[i]
            alloc = alloc - abs(sorted_weigths[i])
        elif alloc > 0:
            sorted_weigths[i] = alloc
            alloc = alloc - alloc
        else:
            sorted_weigths[i] = 0
else:
    pass

sorted_weigths_ = copy.deepcopy(sorted_weigths)
for i in range(sorted_indices.shape[0]):
    sorted_weigths_[sorted_indices[i]] = sorted_weigths[i]

for i in range(len(signs)):
    if signs[i] == True:
        sorted_weigths_[i] = -sorted_weigths_[i]
    else:
        pass

print(output)
print(sorted_weigths_)
```